# Cascading Deletes On Filtered Children - EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, cascading-deletes

Does anyone know what behavior should be expected by attempting to cascade deletes to child entities that are filtered via Map's Requires/HasValue?  I'm curious if I can trust that EF(6) will only cascade the delete to children that make it through the filter, or whether the delete would also be pushed do children that are no longer "pending".

Below is my specific mapping configuration for said child entities.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PendingReviewRecord>().Map(m => m.Requires("Pending").HasValue(true))
    .HasRequired(t => t.Install).WithOptional(t => t.PendingReviewRecord).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

My situation has some further complication in that I am implementing a soft-delete on the "Install" object.. but that is being accomplished via command tree interception so entity still feels it as a delete/removal and not some hacky field modification.

Comment: As far as I know, cascade delete rules are applied to the database and their execution is therefore not handled by EF itself. I would therefore be very much surprised if cascade delete did not affect all children.

Comment: @MortenMertner, That is my exact fear..  I'm hoping someone has implemented or at least tested a similar approach and can confirm before I finish the UI component.  If necessary I suppose I could write another visitor/interceptor set and handle it that way.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, where did your response go?  Accidentally delete it?